# Speed comparison using multiprocessing.Process versus subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, performance, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python3 to execute PYQT code; and at the same time, I need to call Python2.7 code, for operations that I cannot perform via Python3.

I did implement the 2.7 code execution via `Popen`; although it takes a considerable amount of time to run the 2.7 code, when called from `Popen`. The same operation is performed much faster if I run it directly from Python2.7.

Would be possible to use `multiprocessing` instead of `subprocess.Popen` for the same purpose, to speed up the execution of the 2.7 code?
And if that is appropriate; what would be the correct way to call Python2.7 code from a `multiprocessing.Process`? Or is it a waste to use multiprocess, since I am executing only one operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiprocessing` is similar to `subprocess` only on non-POSIX systems that cannot [*fork*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) processes so you could, theoretically, hack away `multiprocessing` to use a different interpreter. It would be more trouble than its worth, tho, because at that point you wouldn't get any performance boost between spawning a `subprocess` and using a `multiprocessing.Process` (in fact, it would probably end slower due to the communication overhead added to `multiprocessing.Process`).

So, if we're talking only about a single task that has to execute in a different interpreter, this is as fast as you're gonna get. If there are multiple tasks to be executed in a different interpreter you may still benefit from `multiprocessing.Process` by spawning a single subprocess to run the different interpreter and then using `multiprocessing` within it to distribute multiple tasks over your cores.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. So there is no benefit at this point in using the `multiprocessing.Process`; I thought that the overhead compared to `subprocess.Popen` was better, and I could gain some speed. At this point I will try to speed up the Python2.7 code, since I already have the best case scenario. It was very educational. Thanks!

Comment: @rataplan - if there is only a single task to be executed, I'm afraid that the only speed up you can gain is to run the subprocess well before it's needed and have it wait for the data to execute (or run it completely separately and use network/pipes to 'transfer' the task). That way, at least at the time of the execution it will work as fast as your system can handle. Also, unless you're transferring a copious amount of data between your subprocesses, the subprocess creation overhead should be negligible (unless you're looking in responses under a second or so)

Comment: Thanks @zwer; I do run in total 2 process; one is running the QT UI via PyQT; the other is running the code via python2.7; and send the output to the caller in Python3, once done. The data copied is not much; since all that I do is to pass a pickle object with all the data saved in there. Thanks again for the extra insight!